# Linux locale - how to disable smart quotes?

Tags: linux, cygwin, gentoo, locale

On my Gentoo system, `find . -regextype help` outputs

```
find: Unknown regular expression type ‘help’; valid types are ‘findutils-default’, ‘awk’, ‘egrep’, ‘ed’, ‘emacs’, ‘gnu-awk’, ‘grep’, ‘posix-awk’, ‘posix-basic’, ‘posix-egrep’, ‘posix-extended’, ‘posix-minimal-basic’, ‘sed’.
```

I always thought *smart quotes* (or whatever they are called) are the scourge of Microsoft software, turns out nobody's protected from that ugliness.
On my other system (Cygwin), `LANG` is set to `en_US.UTF-8`, and *smart quotes* are also displayed. If I unset `LANG` or set it to `en.UTF-8`, output changes to regular single quotes:

```
# unset LANG
# find -regextype help
find: Unknown regular expression type 'help'; valid types are 'findutils-default', 'awk', 'egrep', 'ed', 'emacs', 'gnu-awk', 'grep', 'posix-awk', 'posix-basic', 'posix-eg
rep', 'posix-extended', 'posix-minimal-basic', 'sed'.
```

But on the Gentoo system I mentioned earlier, LANG is unset. Whatever I try to set it (and other locale env vars) to, I see smart quotes and/or a bunch of error messages about incorrect locales.

How to get back my single quotes?

Comment: Such quotes existed in typography for _centuries_ before "Microsoft software", and long before mechanical typewriters merged them into a single tick mark to save keys. They only got that name because of incompatibilities between Windows-1252 (which had them) and ISO-8859-1 (which didn't). So if you could please keep your religion to yourself...

Comment: Thanks, I know that. As a programmer, I really hate the way they are sometimes used in software. Let them have their place in typography, but when I'm copy-pasting some code and some software auto-converts the quotes and then another guy copy-pastes my code and it doesn't work because of wrong quotes - it's just wrong. I understand it makes sense when writing a book in a Word processor, but I think it should be user's choice to enable/disable this behavior (and word processors have option to turn off *auto-correction*).
I'm not asking people to join my religion, just how to disable them here.

Answer (score 0):

This is *not* auto-converted by a smart-quotes system. That text is the direct output of GNU `find`. A some system-wide smart-quotes interpreter would only affect input coming from the keyboard … and I've never heard of one for GNU/Linux/BSD (I found this post because I was looking for how to *en*able it!)

Here's a hex dump of your command output:

```bsh
$ find . -regextype help 2>&1 |head -c99
find: Unknown regular expression type ‘help’; valid types are 
‘findutils-default’, ‘ed’
$ find . -regextype help 2>&1 |head -c99 |hd
00000000  66 69 6e 64 3a 20 55 6e  6b 6e 6f 77 6e 20 72 65  |find: Unknown re|
00000010  67 75 6c 61 72 20 65 78  70 72 65 73 73 69 6f 6e  |gular expression|
00000020  20 74 79 70 65 20 e2 80  98 68 65 6c 70 e2 80 99  | type ...help...|
00000030  3b 20 76 61 6c 69 64 20  74 79 70 65 73 20 61 72  |; valid types ar|
00000040  65 20 e2 80 98 66 69 6e  64 75 74 69 6c 73 2d 64  |e ...findutils-d|
00000050  65 66 61 75 6c 74 e2 80  99 2c 20 e2 80 98 65 64  |efault..., ...ed|
00000060  e2 80 99                                          |...|
```

This makes it easier to see that the output uses the explicit left and right single quotation march characters (U+2018 and U+2019 respectively, see this [Unicode code point table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_mark#Unicode_code_point_table)). In UTF-8, these are represented as `e2 80 98` and `e2 80 99`, which is why you see three dots (which denote non-ASCII characters) on either side of `help` (itself `68 56 5c 70`) and the other quoted words.

You can therefore convert it back with `sed`:

```bsh
$ find . -regextype help 2>&1 |head -c99 \
  |sed "s/\xe2\x80\x98/'/g; s/\xe2\x80\x99/'/g"
find: Unknown regular expression type 'help'; valid types are 
'findutils-default', 'ed'
$ find . -regextype help 2>&1 |head -c99 \
  |sed "s/\xe2\x80\x98/'/g; s/\xe2\x80\x99/'/g" |hd
00000000  66 69 6e 64 3a 20 55 6e  6b 6e 6f 77 6e 20 72 65  |find: Unknown re|
00000010  67 75 6c 61 72 20 65 78  70 72 65 73 73 69 6f 6e  |gular expression|
00000020  20 74 79 70 65 20 27 68  65 6c 70 27 3b 20 76 61  | type 'help'; va|
00000030  6c 69 64 20 74 79 70 65  73 20 61 72 65 20 27 66  |lid types are 'f|
00000040  69 6e 64 75 74 69 6c 73  2d 64 65 66 61 75 6c 74  |indutils-default|
00000050  27 2c 20 27 65 64 27                              |', 'ed'|
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Like many other programs, GNU find uses GNU gettext for l18n. I didn't imply there's some smart-quote system in play after find had printed what it wanted to print, I'm sure it is printed directly by find, but what it prints depends on the locale. Like I mentioned, on one of my systems unsetting LANG or setting it to en.UTF-8 makes the smart quotes disappear, on the other system it doesn't (if I recall correctly, it was the same version of find - the system in question no longer exists so I can't check).

Comment: I understand that I can use sed or whatever post-processor to get rid of those quotes, but what I want is to fix the issue at the source, and make `find` print what I want. It should be just a question of setting the right locale...